# Trying to install Symfony2 but keeps requiring sudo

Tags: symfony

I am trying to install Symfony2, Im on a new mac with MAMP installed. Why is it requiring me to use sudo to do everything from terminal? I am logged in as me and Iam pretty sure I have all the permissions I need.

I have to use sudo for all of these:

```
 sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
 php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /path/to/webroot/Symfony '2.5.*'
 sudo curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Here is one of the errors that I keep getting when I dont run from sudo:

```
 file_put_contents(/Users/myusername/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

My MAMP & htdocs directory has these permissions:

```
MAMP: drwxrwxr-x@ 22 myusername  admin  748 Oct  3 19:04 MAMP 
htdocs: drwxrwxrwx   4 myusername  admin   136 Oct  3 21:46 htdocs
```

This is creating so many permission errors when I try to do anything without using sudo. How can I get around not having to use sudo. Im not a permissions master as I am sure you can gather. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you able to run php without `sudo`? How did you install `php`?

Comment: No I cannot run without sudo. I get error after error. I installed php with MAMP

Comment: What do you get if you run `which php` from terminal? Can you change the permissions of that to make sure you can execute `php` without requiring `sudo`.

Comment: So what's the permission mode of `/usr/bin/php`? Is it at least `-r-xr-xr-x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `.composer` directory is owned by root (*`ls -la ~` to test that*).
If that is the case, chown .composer directory (*recursively*) to your username:

```
sudo chown -R <myusername>:<myusername> /home/<myusername>/.composer
```

Do not forget to replace `<myusername>` with your username.

Comment: I cant even find that directory.

When I try to install composer: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php

I get the following errors: Could not create file /home/composer.phar: fopen(/home/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Operation not supported
Download failed: fopen(/home/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Operation not supported
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: My home directory permissions: dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel        1 Aug 29 20:52 home What is "wheel"?

Comment: Even when I run as sudo curl -sS getcomposer.org/installer | php I get permission errors.

Comment: Ah, that's right ... Mac. I forgot that aspect when I wrote the path.

Comment: Just a note that on mac using `<myusername>:<myusername>` will give you a non-existent group error (on my machine the default user group is a number).  So just use `<myusername>` and chmod will automagically use the default group.